# New point of view: pip dealing with multiple Python versions, Canopy, Anaconda on Linux

Tags: python-2.7, pip, anaconda, canopy

Using pip with different Python version is a common problem, as I see when I search the Internet. There are a lot of answers around, also in this forum. However nobody seems to encounter the same problem that I have:
I use Canopy python most and it was installed first. Later I installed Anaconda. Now when I try to install a program with pip it always install it in Canopy (or refuse to install it because it is already installed in Canopy.
for example:
$ pip install ipython
gives:
Requirement already satisfied...
but there are no ipython in my Anaconda-folder, it is in the /Enthought/Canopy_64bit/... folder
How can I overcome this problem?
Both versions are 2.7 and even if one is 2.7.11 and the other 2.7.12, it did not work to distinguish between the two by this.

Comment: Since you have multiple Python installations on your machine, I suggest making sure that no Python installation is referenced in environment variables (e.g. `PATH`). Then when you want to use a particular Python installation, activate the desired environment. For example with Canopy you can run `source ~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate`. If you have installed Canopy >= v1.6.2, an `activate_canopy` alias should be available to do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following.

Find where both pip-s reside (`whereis pip`, I have it on ~/anaconda2/bin), then `cd` to the pip directory of the python version you want, and execute it from there.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, it did not work. It gave the same results as anywhere else in the file hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I manage with the help of J. Corson comment:
When you want to use a particular Python installation, activate the desired environment. In my chase

```
source /home/per/anaconda_ete/bin/activate
```

then using pip made the installation in the anaconda python and I could install ipython and other stuff there... fine, thanks!